# Alternative domain name to be less confusing

Tags: discussion

So, I can understand how given the domain name space, it could cause some confusion. Anyone have a suggestion that would be less confusing?

The title of the website should remain the same.

Comment: What's confusing about *space*?

Comment: Not covering astronomy.

Comment: `space.stackexchange.com` sounds good to me. Well we can think about changing it when the site has launched just as `stackoverflow.com`. I mean as a domain.

Comment: Considering the down-voting momentum this [Radical proposal: Merge Space Exploration and Astronomy](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/89/49) gained, I don't feel the part about "not covering astronomy" is still valid. Yes, I realize I'm a bit late to the party... but only a fortnight LOL :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"space" is short and catchy - that is what a (sub-) domain is about. Nobody wants to type long stuff into address-bars. So, I like it. No matter how misleading it could be. It is ... space.

Besides, we are not only talking about crafts (hopefully).

Answer (score -2):

http://spacecraft.stackexchange.com

This would make it far less confusing, clearly stating we are talking more about the spacecraft, and less about space in general.

Most of the topics are about spacecraft in some sense, but there is space habitats that might not quite fit under that definition. Still, it could be a closer approach than what we have now.

Comment: That excludes space bases/habitats, resource mining, terraforming, on-planet exploration vehicles (rovers, aerobots, etc), medicine/health, and several other topics, all of which are very important and directly related to space exploration.